# Swift fetch custom annotation information

Tags: swift

I'm trying to present a view controller with an object within annotation `didSelect` function. But it's returning nil when I try to print the `post.id` within the newly presented viewcontroller. If I print `post.id` within the `addAnnotation` function it returns fine.

```
    func addAnnotations(post: Post, title: String?, locationName: String?, coords: [CLLocation]) {
    for coord in coords {
        let CLLCoordType = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coord.coordinate.latitude,
                                                  longitude: coord.coordinate.longitude);
        let anno = MKPointAnnotation()
        anno.coordinate = CLLCoordType

        if title == "" {
            anno.title = locationName
        } else {
            anno.title = title
        }
        mapView.addAnnotation(anno)
    }
}

let activityPreview = ActivityPreviewLauncher()

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    //Returns an error
    guard let post = view.annotation?.post else { return }

    activityPreview.showActivityPreview()
    activityPreview.homeController = self
    activityPreview.post = post
}

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation{
        return nil
    } else{
        let pinIdent = "Pin"
        var pinView: MKPinAnnotationView
        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: pinIdent) as? MKPinAnnotationView {
            dequeuedView.annotation = annotation
            pinView = dequeuedView
        } else {
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: pinIdent)
        }
        return pinView
    }
}
```

Comment: may be you should override delegate methods to made custom annotation?
    optional func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik I have this function I've added it to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of type 'MKAnnotation' has no member 'post'. You have to subclass MKPointAnnotation

```
    class MyAnno: MKPointAnnotation {

    var post: Post? = nil

}
```

in func `addAnnotations` override your code to

```
    let CLLCoordType = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coord.coordinate.latitude,
                                                  longitude: coord.coordinate.longitude);
        let anno = MyAnno()
        anno.coordinate = CLLCoordType
        anno.post = post
        if title == "" {
            anno.title = locationName
        } else {
            anno.title = title
        }
        mapView.addAnnotation(anno)
```

then in `didSelect` check type of your annotation

```
guard 
     let anno = view.annotation as? MyAnno,
     let post = anno.post
     else { return }
```

smth like this